# Listening to text selection changes in monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there an event in monaco editor for text selection ?
I need to respond to a user selecting part of the code in editor?

Is there a better solution to using timer to get ranges for selection ?

Documents don't seem to mention about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`onDidChangeCursorPosition`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ICodeEditor.html#onDidChangeCursorPosition) or [`onDidChangeCursorSelection`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ICodeEditor.html#onDidChangeCursorSelection). to listen for such an event.

```js
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "function hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}",
    language: "javascript"
});

editor.onDidChangeCursorPosition((e) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
});

editor.onDidChangeCursorSelection((e) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
});
```